# cordova run android give error “The system cannot find the path specified.”

Tags: cordova

In a fresh cordova installation, I get the following error:

```
$ cordova run android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171
studio
The system cannot find the path specified.
(node:17492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\myuser\Code\test\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:17492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17492) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Anyone else run across this issue? I've tried re adding the environment variables to my windows 10 system with no success.

Versions:

npm 6.1.0

node 8.11.2

cordova 8.0.0

os: Windows 10

Comment: what is the output of "cordova build android"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event anyone else encounters this issue eventually, here is what I did to resolve it.

- Uninstalled android + android studio as well as deleted any folders in your app data, user folder, + program files.
- Reinstalled android as well as any sdks, virtual devices etc through android studio

I initially installed it through Intellij Idea which is plagued with bugs atm with getting all the android components... I believe that was the problem which was causing some files to be skipped while downloading. 
If you happen to use Intellij Idea as well, uninstall intellij 2018 and get the latest 2017 version, but don't install any of the components through the software. Let android studio do that and then do your edits with Intellij.

Finally, some installations also had some missing files which still caused the cordova run android command to fail. To fix that, I just created a new project and moved over the files.